# How can I create my own spelling file for vim?

Tags: vim, spell-checking

At the moment I'm writing a document where I need to use a lot of acronyms, technical language, and non German words.

Now I was wondering if I could create a spelling file (`tech_speak`) which checks for this technical language so I can use the following vim command

```
:set spelllang=de,tech_speak spell
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `'spellfile'` option is what you're looking for:

```
:set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/techspeak.utf-8.add
```

<sup>Note: Avoid special characters like `_`; as it separates the *region name* in Vim.</sup>

You can then add your custom words to it with `zg`. You don't even need to add anything to `'spelllang'`; those additions will be considered automatically.

Comment: Yeah this looks good but, when I use `zg` vim throws "E751: Output file name must not have region name" at me.

Comment: Ah I needed to remove the `_` so `:set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/techspeak.utf-8.add` works. Thanks!

Comment: You're right; it's best to avoid such characters; I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
:help spell-mkspell
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. But as far as I had read this I need an existing dictionary file. But I want to make a new language file which I can combine with my language.

Comment: A dictionary file can be a simple word list.

Comment: @n.m. So like a csv? Just words separated by commas?

Comment: @Zelphir by newlines IIRC